# Why infix operator (bind) fails when it is declared outside of main file?

Tags: swift, xcode

In my Xcode project, I have a `main.swift` file, with this contents:

```swift
func main() -> Void {
    return print(
        half(80) >>= half >>= half
    )
}

func half(_ a: Int) -> Int? {
    return a % 2 == 0 ? Optional(a / 2) : Optional.none
}

main()
```

In another file, let's call it `test.swift`, I have:

```swift
precedencegroup BindPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: NilCoalescingPrecedence
}

infix operator >>= : BindPrecedence

func >>= <T, U>(_ a: T?, _ k: (T) -> U?) -> U? {
    return a.flatMap(k)
}
```

When I execute main, the following errors display:

```swift
- Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
- Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(Int) -> U?'
- Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'half' is a function
- Type '(Int) -> Int?' cannot conform to 'BinaryInteger'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
- Required by referencing operator function '>>=' on 'BinaryInteger' where 'Self' = '(Int) -> Int?'
```

However, if I put the contents of `test.swift` file below my main function inside `main.swift`, the errors disappear.

Is there any specific rule concerning the declaration of infix operators and precedence groups ? Do I have to put everything inside `main.swift` to make it work ?

I will appreciate any insights into this issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Could it simply be that you have some previous version in your build folder and you need to clean the build folder?

Comment: Thank you so much for testing it, @JoakimDanielson ! I cleaned the build folder and also started a new project. The problem persists. Could you execute this code without errors ?

Comment: @F.Zer try it on a different file (not named main.swift)

Comment: Thank you, @Leo Dabus.  Now I have this error:` left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'half' returns immutable value
`half(80) >>= half >>= half`. Other errors still appear.

Comment: In Command Line Tool project with main.swift and test.swift, I can reproduce 4 out of 5 errors you have shown. But, anyway, `>>=` is a predefined infix operator of AssignmentPrecedence and Right associative. Better not redefine it.

Comment: @OOper's point is the key one. `>>=` is already taken. It means shift-right-assign. Your redefinition in another file doesn't override that. It's worth noting that while this is an entertaining path to explore, it is not particularly fruitful in Swift for many reasons (which is why most folks have abandoned these experiments). For my version, see https://github.com/LlamaKit/LlamaKit (and also https://robnapier.net/flatmap). Still, it's a fun path and there's no problem exploring it. It just doesn't actually make good Swift generally.

Comment: Thank you so much, @OOPer ! That was it ! Really appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, @Rob Napier. Always appreciate your comments and insights.

Answer (score -1):

So the issue is `half >>= half` which is actually trying to match `(Int) -> Int? >>= (Int) -> Int?` which doesn't have an operator for that.

So in my testing I solved it with these changes:

```swift
precedencegroup BindPrecedence {
    associativity: right // This changed
    higherThan: NilCoalescingPrecedence
}

infix operator >>= : BindPrecedence

func >>= <T, U>(_ a: T?, _ k: (T) -> U?) -> U? {
    return a.flatMap(k)
}

func >>= <T, U, V> (_ k1: @escaping (T) -> U?, _ k2: @escaping (U) -> V?) -> (T) -> V? {
    { k1($0).flatMap(k2) }
}
```

I imagine you could get it working with a `associativity: left` like you had it but this has the advantage of short circuiting as soon as one operation gives you `nil`.

Edit:
I'll also add it should work how you have it but type checking is hard. You could likely file this as a bug against the compiler.